# Trouble delaying function with variables passed to it in swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm very new to swift and am having trouble with calling this function again on the 6th line after a delay, Xcode is telling me that

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

I know what the problem is and have tried searching around but haven't been able to make anything work.

```
@objc func attemptToIdentify(_ user: String) {
    if manager.status == .connected {
        socket.emit("identify", user) //This functions correctly
    } else {
        print(manager.status, "... will attempt subscription in 1 second")
        self.perform(#selector(attemptToIdentify(user)), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using matt's suggestions I changed line 6 to 'self.perform(#selector(attemptToIdentify), with: user, afterDelay: 1)' and everything is working now

Comment: Great but I would still suggest that using `perform:with:afterDelay:` at all is a bad idea. There is a Swift way to do a delay and that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `attemptToIdentify(user)` is a *call*. This is not the place for a call; you need a *selector*, i.e. the *name* of a function. So just put `attemptToIdentify`. If you need to pass something, you can pass it in the `with` parameter.

Even better, don't use `perform:afterDelay:` at all. If the idea is to add a delay to a call, just use `asyncAfter` (or my [`delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861) encapsulation of it).

Comment: I see. Updated the code using your suggestions and it works now, thank you!